Why use a macro to call a function instead of calling the function directly in c?
I'm reading a book called 'crafting interpreters' , and I saw a code snippet like this
The function is used to grow the size of a dynamic array.
#define GROW_ARRAY(type, pointer, oldCount, newCount) \ 
        (type*)reallocate(pointer, sizeof(type)*(oldCount), \
          sizeof(type) * (newCount))
//size_t : 无符号整型，表示对象的大小和数组的index
void* reallocate(void* pointer, size_t oldSize, size_t newSize);

Why use a macro to call a function instead of calling the function directly?  What are the benefits and drawbacks?

A real function call causes function parameters ( and some nearby variables/registers ) to be pushed onto the stack, and this pushing & popping can be processor-intensive.  It's argued that although macro pseudo-functions may take more code space, they are faster due to less processor overhead thanks to absence of said stack operations.  That was common knowledge among me/my peers . . . I'm looking forward to someone on S/O with better info to change our minds on this notion.

@user22873067, With C2X and typeof, the type parameter is not needed: #define GROW_ARRAY(pointer, oldCount, newCount), (typeof(pointer))reallocate((pointer), sizeof pointer[0] *(oldCount),  sizeof pointer[0] * (newCount)).

@gregspears that would be true if the macro wasn't just calling a function anyway. The question is only about wrapping a function call in a macro. Besides that, depending on the function, a modern compiler might produce code for function call that is equally efficient.

You might think about what would happen if you need to port that code to a system where you do not have reallocate function but only standard realloc. Changing a macro is much easier than fixing all places where it is used.

I never understood macros like this. If I can remember to type x = macro(type, n) then why can't I as well remember to type x = (type)macro(n)? The programmer needs to be somewhat conscious, they can't just aimlessly call any macro/function with no care in the world about what parameters they pass or no programming practices will save them.

@Lundin, Not repeating yourself has many benefits. What if there's a refactor or a type change. If you forget to change something, the macro will catch it.

@Gerhardh -- oh yes I see that now!  Not sure HOW I missed that, lol, thank you for your kind reply.

@Gerhardh, nah. The macro doesn't help there. Fixing "all the places" could be done by adding #define reallocate realloc

@ikegami that might work if both functions had the same arguments, but they don't.

In this case, it's to introduce type safety.
The following code has an error, but the compiler doesn't catch it.
A *p;
A *q = reallocate( p, i * sizeof( B ), j * sizeof( B ) );

The following code has a different error, but the compiler doesn't catch this one either.
A *p;
B *q = reallocate( p, i * sizeof *p, j * sizeof *p );

It's impossible to make the first error using the macro, and the compiler catches instances of the second error when using the macro.
Also, the call is much simpler using the macro.
GROW_ARRAY( A, p, i, j )


Demo on Compiler Explorer
#include <stdlib.h>

void* reallocate(void* pointer, size_t oldSize, size_t newSize);

#define GROW_ARRAY(type, pointer, oldCount, newCount) \ 
        (type*)reallocate(pointer, sizeof(type)*(oldCount), \
          sizeof(type) * (newCount));          
          
typedef int A;
typedef double B;

int main( void ) {
   int i = 2;
   int j = 4;
   A *p = NULL;  // Whatever. We're not actually running this.

   {
      // This error isn't caught.
      A *q = reallocate( p, i * sizeof( B ), j * sizeof( B ) );
   }

   {
      // This different error isn't caught.
      B *q = reallocate( p, i * sizeof *p, j * sizeof *p );
   }

   {
      // The same error is caught here.
      B *q = GROW_ARRAY( A, p, i, j );
   }
}

<source>:5:55: warning: backslash and newline separated by space
    5 | #define GROW_ARRAY(type, pointer, oldCount, newCount) \
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:6:9: error: initialization of 'B *' {aka 'double *'} from incompatible pointer type 'A *' {aka 'int *'} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    6 |         (type*)reallocate(pointer, sizeof(type)*(oldCount), \
      |         ^
<source>:29:14: note: in expansion of macro 'GROW_ARRAY'
   29 |       B *q = GROW_ARRAY( A, p, i, j );
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~


Note that improvements can be made to the macro, and using the macro might introduce other problems. The Question asks about the purpose of the macro, and this Answer limits itself to addressing that.

Where is there any safety? I can easily write A *p; B *q = GROW_ARRAY( B, p, i, j);. It's simpler to call GROW_ARRAY but in no way safer. One could add type checks in there but the macro definition does not have any.

@Goswin von Brederlow, Added demo

There are several reasons to use a macro in C for meta programming, like calling different functions depending on the operating system or compile flags.
Most others cases have been obsoleted by better compiler capabilities and you should just use static inline functions. The compiler will do the right thing and can even generate better code in many cases. But not so in this case, it's one of the few other cases left that require a macro.
The usage case here is twofold but essentially both the same case:

It modifies the arguments to handle the fact that array sizes are in units of the type and not the memory the array takes. So every size has to be multiplied by sizeof(type). And there is a bug in the code, it does not handle overflows.

It modifies the return type so assigning it to a pointer of different type can give a warning. What it lacks there is a check for the type of the input. And if you do that you might as well just not require the user to specify the type as you can just take it from the given array itself.


The use case is to make the function generic so it can be called with any type despite the fact that it generates different code for every tpye. It hides the tedious conversion of types or from array size to memory size for you. It fails slightly at that due to the type argument. See Lundins answer for how to get rid of that argument and make the macro truly generic.

Re "you can just take it from the given array itself.", That's only possible in C23 which hasn't been completed yet.

@ikegami typeofhas been around for ages. If you mean typeof_unqualthen I'm not even sure I agree with the use of that here. Reallocate is a read/write (or at least copy) operation so I'm not sure calling it on const arrays for example would be the right thing to allow anyway.

@ikegami It has been completed since last week. https://www.iso.org/standard/82075.html

@GoswinvonBrederlow "Reallocate is a read/write (or at least copy) operation so I'm not sure calling it on const arrays for example would be the right thing to allow anyway." Silently casting to a qualified type as in the original code won't fix that either though...

@Lundin, Cool. I did check Wikipedia before posting that, but I guess it hadn't been updated yet. It has now. That said, the point stands: That's only possible in C23, which isn't universally accessible.

@ikegami Both gcc and clang has partial support for it at least. But admittedly one can't use gcc above version 7 or something in real world production.

I'm not saying noone can use it; I'm just listing the limits.
